# Heroku example direct upload to s3 code fails when moved from partial to .js file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, amazon-s3

I've followed the [Heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) for direct upload to s3.  The following gems are pertinent:

aws-sdk, jquery-rails, jquery-ui-rails, and jquery.fileupload-rails

All works perfectly if I put the javascript inside the upload paratial (using `<script></script`).  If, however, I move the javascript to a .js file it fails with the following error: *Uncaught SyntaxError:  Unexpected token <*, so I know the file is being found and parsed.  But the file bugs out.

This is the line the debugger points to: `formData: <%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>,`.

Here is the controller code:

```
def index
        s3 = AWS::S3.new
        @bucket = s3.buckets['mybucket']
        @s3_direct_post = @bucket.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public-read)
end
```

This is the code for the partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user, html: { class: "directUpload" }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar_url %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar_url%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the full javascript code:

```
    $(function() {
    $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
    var fileInput    = $(elem);
    var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
    var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
    var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
    fileInput.after(barContainer);
    fileInput.fileupload({
      fileInput:       fileInput,
      url:             '<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>',
      type:            'POST',
      autoUpload:       true,
      formData:         <%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>,
      paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e name="user[avatar_url]"
      dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
      replaceFileInput: false,
      progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
      },
      start: function (e) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

        progressBar.
          css('background', 'green').
          css('display', 'block').
          css('width', '0%').
          text("Loading...");
      },
      done: function(e, data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
        progressBar.text("Uploading done");

        // extract key and generate URL from response
        var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
        var url   = '//<%= @s3_direct_post.url.host %>/' + key;

        // create hidden field
        var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
        form.append(input);
      },
      fail: function(e, data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

        progressBar.
          css("background", "red").
          text("Failed");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Rails isn't processing your .js file, so that isn't expanded like it is in your partial.

Comment: It is processing other jquery code in the file, and I think it is reading that specific code as it fails on a specific line.  What am I missing?

Comment: In order for that `<%= %>` expression to be expanded, something on the server has to process it. Usually stand-alone JavaScript files are treated as static content, like CSS (which is a good thing, because then clients can cache them). That means that Rails won't be involved when the file is served.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but have you tried using Anaconda to upload files to S3? It handles a lot of the complexities and leaves you with a much simpler job. http://github.com/forgeapps/anaconda

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to go it with as much javascript html 5 as possible.